# Github pages redirect issue

Tags: redirect, web, github, webserver, cname

So I recently deleted the CNAME file off of my github page. But it still points to the same site, how would your recommend I fix this?

For example, say my CNAME was www.google.com. My github page is progdude.github.io.

I deleted the CNAME file, but it still redirects. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your DNS (on Windows use *ipconfig /flushdns* in a command prompt) and [Browser cache](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic), when visiting your site I am not redirected, and the site seems to work fine. If you don't clear it or clearing it doesn't help it should resolve itself within a few days.